# How to do HDR capture based on HAL3?

Tags: camera, android-camera, metadata, android-camera2, hdr

I want to do HDR capture based on HAL3, but i have two problem now.
Problem 1: We know that HDR need to snapshot three image. It can be realized by sending three capture requests, but i don't think it's a good idea. So do you know how to solve this problem?
Problem 2: The HDR need different exposure time to the three image, one image must take a short exposure time, one image must take a middle exposure time and the last one must take a long exposure time.  I want to know how to achieve this effect.

If you have some experience in android camera in HAL3, or you have some example code, can you tell me? I am in troble in this for a long time. Thank you very much!